# Windows cascading contextmenu using ExtendedSubCommandsKey (and python _winreg)

Tags: windows, shell, registry, contextmenu

I was trying to create a cascading context menu in windows 10 using the "ExtendedSubCommandsKey". I tried following [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-create-cascading-menus-with-the-extendedsubcommandskey-registry-entry) on the official microsoft docs, but I can't get it to work.

The endgoal is to register the context menu automattically using python _winreg, but if someone can provide me with registry screenshot of a working cascading context menu using "ExtendedSubCommandsKey", I can figure the rest out.

I think I'm probably doing something wrong on step 2 / step 3. (I can't figure out how the document subcommands from step 2 are used in step 3).

I'm placing the registry entries under "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes" instead of "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT", but this should not matter.

I've searched a lot on google, but I can't really find any good information apart from the Microsoft docs.

Answer (score 1):

A good example and docs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andrew_richards/enhancing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shift-right-click-context-menu-experience)

Comment: URL no longer works. It's never safe to link directly to a Microsoft web page as they are utterly incompetent and break every single URL under their control every couple of years. :) Looks like it is now [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/andrew_richards/enhancing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shift-right-click-context-menu-experience) but I fully expect that to break in the near future as well.

Comment: Updated the link. I disagree with your statement and use of language.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but check out this [article](https://blog.sverrirs.com/2014/05/creating-cascading-menu-items-in.html) it could help as it helped me aswell; I was struggling to add a context menu to .pdf files and I was following literally what Microsot says in their docs but it didn't work at all. So try to play in this directory Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations, I guess it will help as it did for me like magic.

Comment: any affiliation to the linked blog? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: @starball I have no affiliation with the linked blog. I just found it while digging about a solution to my problem in a comment here.